# Presenting the UIImagePickerController causes a crash on iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7

I'm having an issue presenting the UIImagePickerController on iOS 7 devices. I use the following code to present the image picker.

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
cameraUI.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
cameraUI.delegate = self;

[[self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

After the call to presentViewController, the application crashes due to an exec bad access. The console reports the following exceptions.

```
[SBSAccelerometer valueRestriction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1650e360
[__NSCFNumber valueRestriction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146d0e70
```

I enabled zombies to see if an object is getting deallocated prematurely. Zombies reports the following exceptions:

```
[NSISRestrictedToNonNegativeVariable retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x156f0010
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Here is the stack trace I receive with zombies enabled:

[image]

Comment: Are you running this on an actual device? (it may crash on the simulator if I remember correctly.) Also, it may be worth checking that `[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:` doesn't return an empty array for some reason.

Comment: What stack trace are you seeing for the zombie report? Have you tried making a minimal test case? I don't think the code you show is (all of) the problem.

Comment: I'm running the code on an iPhone 5S running iOS 7 which results in a crash, but it works on an iPhone 4 running iOS 6. I checked mediaTypes and public.image and public.movie are being returned.

Comment: Does self exist after the picker is presented? What is presenting the picker?

Comment: I have an update. Yes, self exists after the view controller is presented. The view controller is being presented by another view controller. Also, I'm running into this issue else where in the project when I use presentViewController:animated:completion. It's interesting to note that when I don't animate the transition, I don't experience the crash.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in iOS 7 on iPad. It appears the solution for now is to request permission to photos before opening the UIPopoverControl. Here is how I implemented my solution:

```
**// Photo Library
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    void(^blk)() =  ^() {
        UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        if (NIIsPad()) {
            UIPopoverController* popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
            [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.popoverAnchor permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        } else {
            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }
    };

    // Make sure we have permission, otherwise request it first
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    ALAuthorizationStatus authStatus;
    if (IOS_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
        authStatus = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
    else
        authStatus = ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;

    if (authStatus == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        blk();
    } else if (authStatus == ALAuthorizationStatusDenied || authStatus == ALAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
        [[UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"Grant photos permission" message:@"Grant permission to your photos. Go to Settings App > Privacy > Photos."] show];
    } else if (authStatus == ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
            // Catch the final iteration, ignore the rest
            if (group == nil)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    blk();
                });
            *stop = YES;
        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            // failure :(
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"Grant photos permission" message:@"Grant permission to your photos. Go to Settings App > Privacy > Photos."] show];
            });
        }];
    }
}**
```

Don't forget to add AssetsLibrary.framework to your project.

Comment: I appreciate the answer Vizlix; however, I saw this answer elsewhere on stackoverflow and checked my permissions before I posted the question. Furthermore, the crash is occurring on an iPhone and not an iPad.

Comment: I have been stuck on this or ages. I am using iOS SDK 6.1 and my UIImagePickerController crashes on iPhone4S with iOS7. it works fine on iPhone4 with iOS7 ! Has anyone been able to fix this?